# Does $0$ not in field imply $xy$ not equal to $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

Say there is some field, $F$, where $0$ is not in $F$. It makes intuitive sense that for $xy=0$ to be true, $0$ must be in $F$. How can we prove this, that there does not exist any $x$ or $y$ that make $xy=0$.

Comment: There is always an additive identity in a field, usually written $0$. What are you trying to ask? It is true that if $x,y\neq 0$ then $xy\neq 0$.

Comment: Oy? How can you have a field (or even group) without a neutral element? Normally we just write $0$ for this element.

Comment: If by field you mean the usual algebraic structure "field" that specializes "ring", it is an axiom of fields (and rings) that a zero element belongs to the field.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm trying to prove that there exists no $x$ and $y$ in such a field such that $xy=0$

Comment: @user23899 That seems to have very little to do with whether $0 \in F$.  Also what you just stated you are trying to prove is false (without a small but important correction).

Comment: If we're being pedantic, then the $0\in \Bbb Q$ and the $0\in \Bbb C$ are two different entities (one is a pair of integers, the other a pair of real numbers). So $0_{\Bbb Q}\notin \Bbb C$. But I don't think that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Setting aside the impossibility that $0 \not\in F$, as asserted in your first sentence...  And making a stab at what you're trying to ask in the rest of your question...

Theorem:  Let $x,y \in F$ for some field $F$ and suppose $xy = 0$.  Then either $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Proof:  Fields are [integral domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain).  (That is, fields do not have zero divisors.)

Now the contrapositive of this addresses your comment:  for $x,y \in F$ for some field $F$, if neither $x=0$ nor $y=0$, it must be that $xy \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

By the symbol $0$ if you don't mean additive identity, then it is impossible that $xy=0.$ This is because a field is closed under both of it's operations. Thus for any $x,y \in F$, $xy$ is always in $F$. So if you are taking $0$ as not an element of $F$, then $xy\neq0$ always.

But usually the symbol $0$ is reserved for additive identity. Thus by axioms of fields you have $0 \in F.$ That is, every field always has a unique additive identity denoted by the symbol $0$.

Comment: Why is it true that $x,y\in F$, xy is always in F?

Comment: Because a field is closed under both of it's operations. (By definition of a field) i.e $x+y, xy$ are always the elements of $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that by $0$ you mean the traditional zero, aka additive identity. By definition of a field, there exist such an element in $F$.

> "Say there is some field $F$, where $0$ is not in $F$. "

then, by the property of closure the elemnt $0$ is unreachable from F using its operations $<+,*>$